# Swift Closure as a init argument in a class variable initialized in lazy var that called by function

Tags: ios, swift, class, closures, init

Yesterday i found one pod on github: [3lvis/DATASource](https://github.com/3lvis/DATASource).
Custom class `DATASource` has:

1. Init

   ```
   private init(cellIdentifier: String, fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest, mainContext: NSManagedObjectContext, sectionName: String? = nil, tableConfiguration: ((cell: UITableViewCell, item: NSManagedObject, indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> ())?, collectionConfiguration: ((cell: UICollectionViewCell, item: NSManagedObject, indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> ())?) {
       self.cellIdentifier = cellIdentifier
       self.fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: mainContext, sectionNameKeyPath: sectionName, cacheName: nil)
       self.tableConfigurationBlock = tableConfiguration
       self.collectionConfigurationBlock = collectionConfiguration

       super.init()

       self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = self
       self.fetch()
   }
   ```

   2. Closure as a private var:

      ```
      private var tableConfigurationBlock: ((cell: UITableViewCell, item:     NSManagedObject, indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> ())?
      ```
   3. Internal function:

      ```
      internal func configureCell(cell: UIView, indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
          var item: NSManagedObject?

          let rowIsInsideBounds = indexPath.row <  self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects?.count
          if rowIsInsideBounds {
              item = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? NSManagedObject
          }

          if let item = item {
              if let _ = self.tableView, configuration = self.tableConfigurationBlock {
                  configuration(cell: cell as! UITableViewCell, item: item, indexPath: indexPath)
              } else if let _ = self.collectionView, configuration = self.collectionConfigurationBlock {
                  configuration(cell: cell as! UICollectionViewCell, item: item, indexPath: indexPath)
              }
          }
      }
      ```
   4. Public func that from UITableViewDatasource:

      ```
      public func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
          let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(self.cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)

          self.configureCell(cell, indexPath: indexPath)

          return cell
      }
      ```

Then we create Viewcontroller and initialize DATASource as a lazy variable:

```
lazy var dataSource: DATASource = {
    let request: NSFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "User")
    request.sortDescriptors = [
        NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true),
        NSSortDescriptor(key: "firstLetterOfName", ascending: true)
    ]

    let dataSource = DATASource(tableView: self.tableView, cellIdentifier: CustomCell.Identifier, fetchRequest: request, mainContext: self.dataStack!.mainContext, sectionName: "firstLetterOfName", configuration: { cell, item, indexPath in
        if let cell = cell as? CustomCell {
            cell.label.text = item.valueForKey("name") as? String
        }
    })
    return dataSource

}()
```

Very interesting for me was that part of lazy var with configuration block, that wasn't called first time, and was only called, when tableView asked his delegate cell for row at indexPath:

```
configuration: { cell, item, indexPath in
        if let cell = cell as? CustomCell {
            cell.label.text = item.valueForKey("name") as? String
        }
    })
```

I search for few hours and didn't find any explanation for that. So i wrote some code and tested it. It really works!

```
public class Closuretest {
  private var ConfigurationBlock: ((name: String, type: String) -> ())?


  init(configuration: (name: String, type: String) -> ()) {
    self.ConfigurationBlock = configuration
  }

  //Internal func that will be called by func print
  internal func configureBlock(name: String, type: String) {
    if let conf = self.ConfigurationBlock {
      conf(name: name, type: type)
    }
  }

  public func setLabel(name: String, type: String) {
    self.configureBlock(name, type: type)
  }
}
//New class that will initialize new var with Closuretest var
class NewClass {
  lazy var closure: Closuretest = {
    let test = Closuretest(configuration: { (name, type) in
      print(name)
      print(type)
  })
  return test
  }()

  func giveMeString(name: String, type: String) {
    closure.setLabel(name, type: type)
  }
}

var testVar = NewClass()
testVar.giveMeString("Just a String", type: "True")
```

So the question, why does it work, why this configuration block(closure variable) called only when the class's internal function call it? How to call that type of code, init or can somebody tell what is going on?

Comment: So you're asking why `self.ConfigurationBlock` is only called when you call `testVar.giveMeString` ?

Comment: A lazy declaration is only evaluated when it's value is requested. Does that answer your question?

Comment: @PEEJWEEJ i understand that lazy var is only evaluated when it's reqiuested, but why it's configuration block can be called through class's internal function?

Comment: ConfigurationBlock is a function, and Closuretest.init is being passed a reference to a function. configureBlock is simply calling that reference. Is that what you're wondering?

Comment: @Wain , yes it will work only when the function giveMeString is called, and i can pass some arguments calling that function, that will call another internal function and then return result. Also in this DATASource pod if you will look at tableView function cellForRowAtIndexPath, it's getting the cell that was returned by configuration block.

Comment: @PEEJWEEJ yes! But why i didn't find it in documentation or books, or may be i'm missing something?

Comment: Do you understand that ConfigurationBlock is simply a property of the class? You can access it, call it, etc. just like any other property from within the class. Functions are first class types in Swift

Comment: @PEEJWEEJ ok, now i can understand. It's just a property of the class. Thanks! That answer my question.

Comment: Great, glad I could help!